# how to call a function automatically once all the values are filled

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a form that needs to make some validations to automatically fill another fields, I want that function to be called automatically after all the required values are filled, I tried to do this with one onChange on the last field but it wouldn't work if the user fill that input before the other ones.

any suggestion? this is my api call

```
    const getRFC = ({vLastName,vSecondLastName,vName,vSecondName,vBirthDate}) => {
  ForceApi.post(`/GetRfcController.php`, {  vName, vSecondName, vLastName, vSecondLastName, vBirthDate })
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res.data.resultRFC);
      setvRFC(res.data.resultRFC);
    })
}
```

this are my text inputs and date picker

```
 return ( 
    <ScrollView>
      <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
        <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
          <TextInput style={styles.inputs}
            placeholder="Nombre"
            underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
            onChangeText={newvName => setvName(newvName.toUpperCase())}
            value={vName}
            autoCorrect={false}
            autoCapitalize='characters'
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
          <TextInput style={styles.inputs}
            placeholder="Segundo nombre"
            underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
            onChangeText={newvSecondName => setvSecondName(newvSecondName.toUpperCase())}
            value={vSecondName}
            autoCorrect={false}
            autoCapitalize='characters'
          />
          </View>
          <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
            <TextInput style={styles.inputs}
              placeholder="Apellido paterno"
              underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
              onChangeText={newvLastName => setvLastName(newvLastName.toUpperCase())}
              value={vLastName}
              autoCorrect={false}
              autoCapitalize='characters'
            />
          </View>
          <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
            <TextInput style={styles.inputs}
              placeholder="Apellido materno"
              onChangeText={newvSecondLastName => setvSecondLastName(newvSecondLastName.toUpperCase())}
              underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
              value={vSecondLastName}
              autoCorrect={false}
              autoCapitalize='characters'
            />
          </View>
          <View style={styles.containerdate}>
            <DatePicker 
              date={vBirthDate} //initial date from state
              mode="date" //The enum of date, datetime and time
              placeholder="select date"
              format="DD/MM/YYYY"
              minDate="01/01/1900"
              maxDate="01/01/2019"
              confirmBtnText="Confirm"
              cancelBtnText="Cancel"
              androidMode="spinner"
              customStyles={{
                placeholderText: {
                  fontSize: 16,
                },
                dateIcon: {
                  height: 0,
                  width: 0,
                },
                dateText: {
                  color: '#b3b4b5',
                  fontSize: 16,
                },
                dateInput: {
                  borderWidth: 0,
                }
              }}
              onDateChange={(date) => {setvBirthDate(date);} }
            />
          </View>
```

this is the text input that has to be updated with the value of the api

```
         <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
            <TextInput style={styles.inputs}
              placeholder={vRFC}
              underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
              value= {vRFC}
              editable={false} 
              selectTextOnFocus={false}
              autoCorrect={false}
              autoCapitalize='characters'
            />
          </View>
```

I have tried this

```
useEffect(() => {
if (vLastName && vSecondLastName && vName && vSecondName && vBirthDate) {
    getRFC();
}
}, [vLastName, vSecondLastName, vName, vSecondName, vBirthDate]);
```

I tried this but at the moment that every field is filled it throws me a warning and doesn't execute the function, the warning says that `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_ref2.vLastName')]`

which is weird because when I use the button that I made (that just calls the function) nothing wrong happens

any help would be appreciated

edit----- this is how I declare the states

```
    const [vName, setvName] = useState('');
const [vSecondName, setvSecondName] = useState('');
const [vLastName, setvLastName] = useState('');
const [vSecondLastName, setvSecondLastName] = useState('');
const [vCellphone, setvCellphone] = useState('');
const [vBirthDate, setvBirthDate] = useState('');
const [vRFC, setvRFC] = useState('RFC');
const [vGender, setvGender] = useState(1);
const [vEmail, setvEmail] = useState('');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const getRFC = ({vLastName,vSecondLastName,vName,vSecondName,vBirthDate}) => {
```

declaration defines object as an parameter

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (vLastName && vSecondLastName && vName && vSecondName && vBirthDate) {
    getRFC();
  }
}, [vLastName, vSecondLastName, vName, vSecondName, vBirthDate]);
```

`getRFC()` called without parameters ... so `undefined` ... and this undefined doesn't contain `vLastName`, reason of warning

**SOLUTION:** Pass parameters or remove from `getRFC` declaration if they are in scope.

Comment: you dont have idea how much you helped me, thanks a lot

Comment: I'm glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

You could set the values of the fields in the state and then as each value is filled in check the state for the others. If all values are met then execute the function.

Comment: isnt that what i do here?
useEffect(() => {
if (vLastName && vSecondLastName && vName && vSecondName && vBirthDate) {
    getRFC();
}
}, [vLastName, vSecondLastName, vName, vSecondName, vBirthDate]);

Comment: If you console.log your state are those values actually set?

Comment: yeah they are setted at the momento they are filled, i have cosole.logedthem

Comment: Can you show the code where ```vName, vSecondName, vLastName, vSecondLastName, vBirthDate``` are declared?